# change cell content displayed on click - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

does it exist a library or some function set which does the following_

[image]

Discalimer: when the page is loaded, all the content "beneath" A through E is to be loaded and then I simply want to display at will according to a change (on click of the buttons). I think this is done in javascript but I am too green to deal with this level of complexity myself thus seeking advice to more experienced users.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Thank you. exactly what I was looking for. just a little follow up: how to change the formatting and the filling of the tabs' buttons ? in order to make them prettier and all. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at using Jquery as was mentioned in a comment.
https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Or you can look at using a front end framework such as Bootstrap
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("li").on("click",function(){

     $("li").removeClass("clicked");

     $(this).addClass("clicked");

     $(".content").text("This is : " + $(this).text());
    
     })
  
 })
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.content {
  border: 3px solid skyblue;
  height: 200px;  
  width: 460px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
.clicked {
  border:3px solid skyblue;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="clicked">A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <div class="content"></div>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```